# Is it possible to play two animations with different rate functions simultaneously?

Tags: animation, manim

Suppose that I wanted to rotate a line in a linear fashion and summon a text mobject with the `GrowFromCenter` animation at the same time. The thing is, text growing in a linear fashion looks awkward to my taste and I want it to grow smoothly. Is there a way I can play two animations, one with `smooth` and the other with `linear` rate functions simultaneously?

Below is only a simplified code to describe the situation.

```
class test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        phi = ValueTracker(0)
        line = Line(ORIGIN,(2,0,0))
        sample_text = TextMobject("Text")
        sample_text.shift(LEFT*2)
        line.add_updater(lambda d: d.set_angle(phi.get_value()))
        self.add(line)
        self.play(
            GrowFromCenter(sample_text),
            phi.increment_value,PI/2,
            rate_func = linear
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
class test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        phi = ValueTracker(0)
        line = Line(ORIGIN,(2,0,0))
        sample_text = TextMobject("Text")
        sample_text.shift(LEFT*2)
        line.add_updater(lambda d: d.set_angle(phi.get_value()))
        self.add(line)
        self.play(
            GrowFromCenter(sample_text,rate_func = linear),
            phi.increment_value,PI/2,{"rate_func":smooth}
        )
```

Comment: self.play(thetaT.animate.set_value(angleX),run_time=5, rate_func=linear)
self.play(radiusT.animate.set_value(2),run_time=3, rate_func=smooth)
In ManimGL, how can I put those two valueTracker animate in the same play.  because I want they play at the same time